# Dictionary value not updating as expected when using -=

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, counter

I have a dictionary and a word:

```
check = {'a': 3, 'e': 1, 'p': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1}
word = 'rapturerererer'
```

I'm looking to run a test if all the letters from `word` are in `check`.  So I need to keep a running count of all the used up letters and check if there are any negatives at the end.

I have code but it always caps out the values at 0 and never returns the negative values:

```
for letter in word:
    if check.get(letter):
        check[letter] -= 1
print(check)

{'a': 2, 'p': 1, 'r': 0, 'e': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0}
```

What I'm expecting is this:

```
{'a': 2, 'p': 1, 'r': -5, 'e': -4, 't': 0, 'u': 0}
```

Can anyone explain why it's stopping at 0 for these values?

Comment: `if 0` evaluates to `False` - change the conditon to `if check.get(letter) is not None`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if check.get(letter):
    check[letter] -= 1
```

`if check.get(letter)` doesn't only fail if `letter` is missing; it also fails if the value in the dict is ["falsy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false). `None` is falsy, and so is `0`. Once it hits `0` the test fails and no more decrementing happens.

Use `in` instead.

```
if letter in check:
    check[letter] -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error occurs because checking `if d.get(x)` assesses the nature of the value (i.e. whether it is 0 or `False`-like) rather than *just* the existence of the key.

An alternative is to use `collections.Counter` followed by a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

check = {'a': 3, 'e': 1, 'p': 2, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1}
word = 'rapturerererer'

word_count = Counter(word)

res = {k: check[k] - word_count[k] for k in check}

print(res)

{'a': 2, 'e': -3, 'p': 1, 'r': -5, 'u': 0, 't': 0}
```

This will work because `Counter` objects return 0 value for a key which has not been added.